# How to refresh collection-repeat list when the value is changed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a collection-repeat element with lots of data on the view and I want to change its sorting when I select an option from the  element. Although it assigns the correct value to the $scope.isAscending variable, collection-repeat list is not updating.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
  <ion-content on-scroll="onContentScroll()">
    <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select item-light">
      <div class="input-label">
        Sorting:
      </div>
      <select ng-model="selectField" ng-change="chooseSorting(selectField)">
        <option value="true">ascending</option>
        <option value="false">descending</option>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="q">
        </label> 
    </div>

    <div collection-repeat="item in items | orderBy: item.year: !isAscending | itemFilter: q  | groupByProperty" divider-collection-repeat>
        <ion-item  class="item item-thumbnail-left item-button-right">
            <a class="item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="openModal(item)">
              <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
              <p>{{item.properties[0]}}</p>
              <p>{{item.properties[3]}}</p>
            </a>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I tried to call $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.isAscending = value}) after the option was specified, It updates the scope value, but it doesn't refresh the repeating list, $state.go() doesn't work either. 
Is there a way to refresh collection-repeat list ?

Comment: `itemFilter: q` what's `q`?

Comment: where was a search field, I accidently deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question well, you want to filter the `year` based on `select` changes, right?

If so, first you don't need to use `ng-change` and second `orderBy` *filter* just needs the `property` (in your case `year`).

1. Change your `select` to:

```
<select ng-model="selectField">
   <option value="">ascending</option>
   <option value="false">descending</option>
</select>
```

2. Change your `repeat` to:

```
<div collection-repeat="item in items | orderBy: year: selectField | itemFilter: q  | groupByProperty" divider-collection-repeat>
```

Take a look on docs of [**orderBy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter.

Comment: Well, what are those other filters?

Comment: itemFilter is for filtering out items by search query, groupByProperty and other directive are for adding dividers to the list. If I change item.year to year it still doesn't refresh the view

Comment: Pleasure to help :D